# Tie the line to the end of ListView

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, listview, distance

In eclipse all looks good, but on the device between  line and  listview have a big distance.
How to remove the distance between the list and the line?
Here the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical" >   
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reminder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
           />        
    <View 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="6dp"
     android:background="@drawable/line_top"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="18dp"     
      />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.91" 
        >   
    </ListView>
    <View 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="6dp"
      android:background="@drawable/line_bottom"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"  
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: in eclipse]![image: on device]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the margin_top="18dp" inside that View.
Remove the layout weight that you have set to listview.

Answer (score 0):

you can use relaytiveLayout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:orientation="vertical" >   
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reminder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:align_parentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
       />        
<View 
 android:id="+@id/top_line"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="6dp"
 android:background="@drawable/line_top"
 android:layout_below="+@id/reminder"
 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="18dp"     
  />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_below="+@id/top_line"
    >   
</ListView>
<View 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="6dp"
  android:background="@drawable/line_bottom"
 android:layout_below="+@id/mainList"
 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"  
  />
</RelativeLayout >
```